# I want to use multiple templates (elements) in same page in cakephp 4

Tags: cakephp

I want to use multiple templates (elements) in same page in cakephp 4. now its worked only one element at page load. i want use 2 elements in same page. my code is

1. echo $this->element('upload_template_batch_attendance');
2. echo $this->element('upload_template_notes');

Comment: no one and nothing prevents you from using them